# Counting a series of characters in C

Tags: c, character, counting

All it's supposed to do is count the characters a user enters, and print it out. Can't use arrays, and must be terminated by the user. I have no idea what's wrong with this. Any tips?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  int input;

  printf( "Enter a series of characters:\n" );

  input  = getchar( );

  while ( input != EOF )
    {
    input++;
    input = getchar( );
    }

  printf( "You entered %d characters.\n", input );

  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you intend `input` to hold the current input, or the number of characters you've read? You currently seem to be trying to use it for both, but it can only hold one or the other.

Answer (score 3):

Your input variable `input` is also being used as the counter.

Comment: Thanks, I was following a weird template. I have it all sorted now!

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `input` variable for two different things:

- to get the next character from `stdin`
- and to count the total number of characters entered.

The first usage messes up the second: using `input` to store the next character, you overwrite the character count.

You need 2 different variables for the two different purposes.

```
int input;
int characterCount = 0;

// your loop:
    characterCount++;
    input = getchar( );
```

Answer (score 1):

Comments inline

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  int input;

  printf( "Enter a series of characters:\n" );

  input  = getchar( );

  while ( input != EOF )
    {
/* Good so far - you have read a char from the user */
    input++;
/* Why are you increment the user entered char by 1 - you need a separate counter */
    input = getchar( );
/* Now you read another char from the user (to be mangled on next loop iteration */
    }

  printf( "You entered %d characters.\n", input );

  return 0;

}
```